# Adding to an Integer already in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I have an already existing `ArrayList<Integer>` and I'd like to add 1 to an `Integer` at a specific index. However, it gives me the error that "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable." It's something like this:

```
arrayListOfIntegers.get(i) += 1;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `+=` operation is supposed to act on a variable--a local variable, a field, etc. And Integers are immutable, so you can't really change their value directly--5 will always be 5, and if you add 1 to it, you end up with a new number (6).

So you need to first "get" the value that is at the given index, and then "set" the value at that index to the new number that comes from adding one to the original value:

```
arrayListOfIntegers.set(i, arrayListOfIntegers.get(i) + 1);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this change is necessary.

Comment: @Arkanon: I was working on it. Does this new explanation make sense?

Comment: @dfriend21 because `Integer` is immutable and, on top of that, [**Java is pass by value, never by reference**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197).

Answer (score 0):

Your not assigning the value to anything you need to do

```
arrayListOfInteger.set(i, (arrayListOfIntegers.get(i) + 1));
```